# How to pass Location header to response with command(API) and query(odata) controllers

Tags: asp.net-core, http-headers, location, odata

**Scenario**

I have command API controller written in ASP.Net core 2.2. Controller inherited from *ControllerBase* and has attribute *ApiController*. I would like to add Location header. I have also query odata controller. *Odata version: 7.2.2*.

**Odata codes:**

My Odata controller:

```
[ODataRoutePrefix("categories")]
public class ODataCategoriesController : ODataController
```

Odata Get action:

```
[EnableQuery]
[ODataRoute("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<Category>> GetAsync(Guid id)
```

**Startup**

```
opt.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
...
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseMvc(options =>
{
     options.EnableDependencyInjection();
     options.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().Expand().MaxTop(100).SkipToken();
     options.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "api/odata", GetExplicitEdmModel());
});
```

**Tried**

I've tried using CreatedAtAction but I received: *InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.*

In my POST controller:

```
return CreatedAtAction("Get", "ODataCategories", new { id= categoryResponse.Id }, categoryResponse);
```

**Tried 2**

I have also tried with return Location header manually. But I recieved:
*Header is not present in response.*

**Code**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CreateCategoryResponse>> PostCategory(
        [FromBody]CreateCategoryCommand createCategoryCommand)
    {
        CreateCategoryResponse categoryResponse =
            await _mediator.Send(createCategoryCommand);

        if (categoryResponse == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        HttpContext.Response.Headers["Location"] = 
            $"SomeBuiltLocation";
        return Created("", categoryResponse);
    }
```

**Summary**

I am looking for solution which enable me to include Location header. It does not matter if it be with CreatedAt or by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to create it by hand as well.

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
public async Task<ActionResult<CreateCategoryResponse>> PostCategory(
    [FromBody]CreateCategoryCommand createCategoryCommand) {
    CreateCategoryResponse categoryResponse =
        await _mediator.Send(createCategoryCommand);

    if (categoryResponse == null) {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var result = new CreatedResult("SomeBuiltLocation", categoryResponse);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you know whether it is possible to create Location header by refering to odata controller action?